# jQuery return function inside if loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the format of `jQuery` function I am using. I need to exit from the entire `js-validation` function if `condition 3` fails.

I have tried using `return false` and `return`, However the function is not getting exited ,  `$.post` in the subsequent part is getting executed.

Any help please?

```
$("body").on("click", ".js-validation", function(event) {
    if (condition 1) {
        /* doing something*/
    } else {
        if (condition 2) {
            $.get( "abc-json.php",{value:value} ).done(function(data) {
                if (condition 3) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            $.post();
        }
    });
```

Comment: FYI, `if` is not _loop_.

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous function here. To return response from async callback, see the answers on the linked question.

Comment: Those are known as nested `if`s, a loop is used to describe repeating code such as a  `for` or `while`.